# How to properly authenticate an HTTP request for Google Analytics Real Time Reporting API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I'm using the Google Analytics Real Time Reporting API to display a list of active users on my web page by dispatching an action in React that uses an Axios request to request data from the google api but I'm having troubles with the HTTP request to do this.

```
export const REALTIME_API_KEY_ID =[MY API KEY];
export const REALTIME_API_VIEW_ID = 'ga:[MY VIEW ID HERE]'
export const GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_API_ROUTE = `https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/realtime?ids=${REALTIME_API_VIEW_ID}&metrics=rt:activeUsers&key=${REALTIME_API_KEY_ID}`

const fetchActiveUsersFromGoogleAnalytics = (dispatch) => {
  axios
  .get(GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_API_ROUTE)
  .then((data) => dispatch(saveActiveUsers(data)));
}
```

I keep an getting Error 401 while trying to do this

```
"code":401,"message":"Login Required"
```

How can I achieve what I want to do?

Comment: Did you ever do it? You need to try harder yourself first if you want to get help on this website I find. Why are you exporting the const's variables? Why did'nt you get the view ID?